# Issue with checking for current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a view which has a "Like" button on it. Before it displays that like button it checks to see if the user has already liked it or not. This is the code for that like "button".

```
<% if current_user.can_like_photo?(@photo) %>
  <%= link_to "Like", :controller => "likes", :action => 'create', :method => "post", :id => @photo.id %>
<% else %>
  <span class="caption">&check; Liked</span>
<% end %>
```

This works fine; **IF** there is a `current_user`. However, if you're not logged it spits out an exception because there is no `current_user`. The exception is caught before the page loads, not when the like link is clicked; just to be clear. This is my `current_user` method in my application_helper:

```
def current_user
  User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

What is the best way to make this work if there is no `current_user` logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% if current_user &&  current_user.can_like_photo?(@photo) %>
```

You may also need the following if it is an ActiveRecord exception:

```
def current_user
  User.find(session[:user_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  false
end
```

Comment: Yup, this worked for me. I'm unfamiliar with `rescue` but I'll look it up. Thanks!

Comment: The find method will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception if the record does not exist.  rescue catches the exception.  The false is there as the last line executed is always returned.  Please see my edits to specify which exception you are catching.

Answer (score 2):

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% if current_user.can_like_photo?(@photo) %>
    <%= link_to "Like", :controller => "likes", :action => 'create', :method => "post", :id => @photo.id %>
  <% else %>
    <span class="caption">&check; Liked</span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Where

```
def logged_in?
  params[:session_id].presence
end
```

Comment: Thanks @floor. I gave this a go, but `presence?` was not recognized. I tried `present?` which seemed to work, except the like button was then gone for logged in users as well. I may try this way in future if I need more functionality out of this.

Comment: Scratch that. I got this working too. I wish I could accept this answer too, since both of them were needed to fully fix my issue.